# Why do two of my SVGs load as the same one in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, svg, figma

This is almost definitely an issue with the SVG code itself. I have 2 SVGs from Figma and I load them into ReactJS as ReactComponents, regular stuff. Issue is that for some reason React sees them as the same SVG despite their SVG code being different. I suspect this to be an issue within the SVG code of these 2 SVGs because the same issue does not occur with other SVGs.

This is one SVG (I shorten the xlink:href in the end as it is too long):

```
<svg width="1215" height="550" viewBox="0 0 1215 550" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="Group 9">
<rect id="Thousand-02 1" y="16" width="696.273" height="534" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
<path id="element2" d="M1194.87 470.154C1192.44 465.157 1194.81 459.222 1200.08 456.911C1205.35 454.599 1211.6 456.848 1214.04 461.846C1216.48 466.843 1214.11 472.778 1208.84 475.089C1203.57 477.401 1197.31 475.152 1194.87 470.154ZM1197.77 468.905C1199.48 472.403 1203.83 473.965 1207.59 472.341C1211.27 470.716 1212.92 466.593 1211.21 463.033C1209.5 459.472 1205.15 457.973 1201.39 459.597C1197.71 461.221 1196.06 465.407 1197.77 468.905Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
<path id="element" d="M738.216 20.5325L738.137 14.0237C738.171 13.7748 738.382 13.5477 738.657 13.4976L745.55 13.4265C745.813 13.4593 746.024 13.2323 746.07 12.9004L746.038 9.2672C746.072 9.0183 745.832 8.81957 745.48 8.77585L738.588 8.84686C738.324 8.81407 738.083 8.61534 738.03 8.35551L737.951 1.84671C737.985 1.5978 737.745 1.39908 737.393 1.35535L733.546 1.38317C733.282 1.35038 733.072 1.57742 733.026 1.90929L733.105 8.41809C733.071 8.66699 732.86 8.89404 732.585 8.94421L725.692 9.01524C725.429 8.98245 725.218 9.20949 725.172 9.54136L725.204 13.1746C725.17 13.4235 725.41 13.6222 725.762 13.6659L732.654 13.5949C732.918 13.6277 733.159 13.8264 733.212 14.0863L733.291 20.5951C733.257 20.844 733.497 21.0427 733.849 21.0864L737.696 21.0586C737.971 21.0084 738.182 20.7814 738.216 20.5325Z" fill="#FDD08D"/>
</g>
<defs>
<pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
<use xlink:href="#image0" transform="translate(0 -0.0282801) scale(0.00151745 0.00197858)"/>
</pattern>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="1200.22" y1="456.866" x2="1208.02" y2="475.462" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#BFF0DD"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#57D2A3"/>
</linearGradient>
<image id="image1" data-name="Thousand-02.png" width="659" height="534" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAApMAAAIWCAYAAAALawaWAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAz4ESURBVHgB7L0JoF5VdS++9nfnm5vkZiRzLpAAYUyYFdEg4KwEaat9ao19RUFtwf+Tvvbpe4TWZ/vap6CtA9oK2tr2WZXBeSJBQWYIIPOQG8g83uQmueN31n9Pa++199nnu98NSbiB80u
```

And this is the other SVG:

```
<svg width="1415" height="654" viewBox="0 0 1415 654" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="Group 8">
<rect id="thousand-01 1" x="728" width="687" height="654" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
<path id="element3" d="M606.673 131.912L605.75 125.469C605.75 125.218 605.918 124.967 606.169 124.883L612.628 123.962C612.88 123.962 613.048 123.711 613.048 123.377L612.545 119.778C612.545 119.527 612.293 119.36 611.957 119.36L605.498 120.28C605.247 120.28 604.995 120.113 604.911 119.862L603.989 113.418C603.989 113.167 603.737 113 603.401 113L599.794 113.502C599.543 113.502 599.375 113.753 599.375 114.088L600.298 120.531C600.298 120.782 600.13 121.033 599.878 121.117L593.419 122.038C593.168 122.038 593 122.289 593 122.623L593.503 126.222C593.503 126.473 593.755 126.64 594.09 126.64L600.549 125.72C600.801 125.72 601.053 125.887 601.137 126.138L602.059 132.582C602.059 132.833 602.311 133 602.646 133L606.253 132.498C606.505 132.414 606.673 132.163 606.673 131.912Z" fill="#FDD08D"/>
<path id="element" d="M652.909 630.154C650.602 625.157 652.846 619.222 657.834 616.911C662.821 614.599 668.743 616.848 671.05 621.846C673.356 626.843 671.112 632.778 666.125 635.089C661.138 637.401 655.215 635.152 652.909 630.154ZM655.652 628.905C657.272 632.403 661.387 633.965 664.94 632.341C668.431 630.716 669.99 626.593 668.369 623.033C666.748 619.472 662.634 617.973 659.08 619.597C655.589 621.221 654.031 625.407 655.652 628.905Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
<path id="element2" d="M1.18132 345.401C-1.81721 338.904 1.10028 331.189 7.58359 328.184C14.0669 325.179 21.7658 328.103 24.7644 334.599C27.7629 341.096 24.8454 348.811 18.3621 351.816C11.8788 354.821 4.17986 351.897 1.18132 345.401ZM4.74714 343.776C6.85422 348.324 12.203 350.354 16.8223 348.243C21.3606 346.131 23.3867 340.772 21.2796 336.142C19.1725 331.513 13.8238 329.564 9.20442 331.676C4.6661 333.787 2.64006 339.228 4.74714 343.776Z" fill="url(#paint1_linear)"/>
</g>
<defs>
<pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
<use xlink:href="#image0" transform="scale(0.0014556)"/>
</pattern>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="657.971" y1="616.866" x2="666.07" y2="635.144" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#BFF0DD"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#57D2A3"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint1_linear" x1="7.7622" y1="328.126" x2="18.2915" y2="351.887" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#BFF0DD"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#57D2A3"/>
</linearGradient>
<image id="image0" data-name="thousand-01.png" width="687" height="654" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAq8AAAKOCAYAAACIkfAOAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUABANcSURBVHgB7P0JnFxHft8J/iIzK+sGqnADBMEim1ffQHdLsqYtEZTGktsaqdmWPZLtsUjtyvJovOtm27OzO+ORAVpH2
```

Comment: What's the relevant code you are using in react?? Maybe a sandbox will be a lot helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad  
My ReactComponent imports are written as
`import {ReactComponent as NewWayBG} from '../assets/newway-bg.svg'
import {ReactComponent as HomeBG} from '../assets/home-bg.svg'`

I am also using material ui if it matters

Comment: please share those actual svg files with google drive/ docs/pastebin/ github gist.... can not re-produce it, without them...

Comment: The have duplicate id values. All id values must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the id of the pattern object. Make sure to update `<rect ... fill="url{#<your_pattern_id>}">`. This should fix the problem.